# phabricator get the subscribers of a commit

Tags: php, xmpp, phabricator

I am trying to integrate Phabricator notification system with jabber chat.I am polling feed.query to get the recent stories. I have written a botfeednotificationhandler that polls the feed.query. Suppose A is the author of a commit for which B and C are subscribers. If B comments on the story, then I can get the authorPHID of A using the objectPHID of the comment story using diffusion.querycommits.
Now I also want to get the PHID of C who is the original subscriber of A. I want to notify C that B has commented on a story of A.

How can I get the PHID of C from the comment story that B has produced. Or how can I find the subscribers to a story?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't think of a way through conduit for this.  But, doesn't Phabricator already send messages to subscribers?  What is the need for a second message?

Comment: @CEPA I want to send the message to jabber chat.